# Pylint issue in Python 3.11

Tags: importerror, lint, pylint, python-3.11

I am getting import error when running lint
I am using pylint version 3.0.2 and python version 3.11

Getting the below error

```
 from pylint.interfaces import IAstroidChecker, ITokenChecker
ImportError: cannot import name 'IAstroidChecker' from 'pylint.interfaces' (/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pylint/interfaces.py)
```

I tried using the same with python 3.9 and everything works fine.

Comment: https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/9144

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with python 3.11.
The error goes away using an older version (<3) of pylint.